# height for a tag as a button is not resizing

Tags: html, css, web

I have this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="homebox">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.homebox {
    width: 20%;

    min-height: 300px;
    height: 45%;
    max-height: 50%;

    position: absolute;
    margin: 10% auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

.homebox > ul {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5% auto;
}

.homebox > ul li {
    margin-bottom: 11%;
    width: 100%;
}

.homebox > ul li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 30%;
    background: #34696f;
    border: 2px solid rgba(33, 68, 72, 0.59);

    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 3.2em/100px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;

    text-decoration: none;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #34696f, #2f5f63);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #34696f, #2f5f63);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #34696f, #2f5f63);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #34696f, #2f5f63);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #34696f, #2f5f63);

    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;

    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.homebox > ul li a:hover {
    background: #3d7a80;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #3d7a80, #2f5f63);
}

.homebox > ul li a:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #1b383b;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #1b383b;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #1b383b;

    text-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

I have a div box that stays in the center and it has a relative width and height from the outer div or body. I want my a tag inside ul li to be responsive to the div box. Anchor tag's height inside the li is not resizing when the homebox div resizes, what should I do?

Comment: which height is not working?

Comment: the height of .homebox > ul li a, lemme edit my question

Comment: Your height is in percentage so, it's not working, tell me if it works with pixels...

Comment: it does, so i should set the min, height, and max as pixels? I want the height to change if the div box resizes. @C-linkNepal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting height in percentage so it is not working. The value with percentage only works in IE. To make it work in other browsers too, you should set a fixed pixel height in your parent div. To make it easy just add the following code in your css:

```
html,body{height: 100%;}
```

Comment: i fixed the problem by setting height in percentage in the ul tag and li so the a tag inside the li's can get the height from the parent tag, i guess. Thanks for the hint. @C-link Nepal